# How to borrow a struct's curried function field?

Tags: rust, traits, currying, borrow-checker, parser-combinators

I have a struct, `Parser` with a field, `transformer` meant to hold a function. This function returns a closure, which processes a `ParserState` and returns a `ParserState`. I have made a function, `str_parser`, which I am using as a transformer for a new instance of a `Parser`.

```rust
pub struct Parser<F> 
    where F: FnOnce(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    pub transformer: F
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct ParserState {
    pub target: String,
    pub index: usize,
    pub result: Option<String>, // the container of eventual results from the parsing, with Some(result) or None
    pub error: bool,            // whether we've encountered an error; index -> 0, Some(err_msg)
    pub err_msg: Option<String> // Eventual error message
}

impl<F> Parser<F> 
    where F: FnOnce(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    pub fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        // creating a new Parser just means deciding on which closure it applies
        Parser {
            transformer: f,
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self, corpus: String) -> ParserState {
        let state = ParserState {
            target: corpus,
            index: 0,
            result: None,
            error: false,
            err_msg: None
        };
        return (self.transformer)(state);
    }
}

pub fn str_parser(needle: String) -> impl FnOnce(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    let parser = move |state: ParserState| {
        let target_string = state.target;
        let index = state.index;
        if target_string[index..needle.len()] == needle {
            ParserState {
                target: target_string,
                index: index + needle.len(),
                result: Some(needle),
                error: false,
                err_msg: None
            }
        } else {
            ParserState {
                target: String::from(""),
                index: 0,
                result: None,
                error: true,
                err_msg: Some(String::from("Error"))
            }
        }
    };
    parser
}
```

The borrow-checker is refusing to let me apply this function to the supplied parameter after currying, because of this error:

```rust
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `self.transformer` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/parsers.rs:32:16
   |
32 |         return (self.transformer)(state);
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.transformer` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How do I go about this? Implementing the `Copy` trait in this scenario seems daunting to me. Is there a way to make this a legal move, while still allowing me to do curry this `str_parser` function?

Comment: `FnOnce` can only be called once (Calling it takes `self` where `self` is the closure). `Fn` can be called multiple times but cannot modify state (Calling it takes `&self` where `self` is the closure). `FnMut` can be called multiple times and can modify state (Calling it takes `&mut self` where `self` is the closure). If you want your closure to copy state instead of being able to modify it, then make it `FnOnce + Copy` or `FnOnce + Clone`. If you want your closure to read but not invalidate state, make it `Fn`. If you want your closure to do with as it wished, make it `FnMut`.

Comment: Does it make sense to call `run()` more than once on the same `Parser`? If not, you could put `transformer` inside an `Option` -- [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e63700f5f9a4d29cfc39316ee59f586d). If `run` should be callable more than once, you probably want to use `FnMut` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It turns out that `Fn` was the proper choice. I used it and modified the closure to use `needle.clone()` and that worked.

Comment: @trentcl For the moment it does not make sense to call `.run()` more than once, so your suggestion makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I have a `Parser` which does not have any state beyond the `transformer`. Therefore, I did not need to use `FnOnce`. `Fn` was all I needed. From there, I modified the closure used in my `str_parser` function to clone the `needle` string:

```rust
pub struct Parser<F> 
    where F: Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    pub transformer: F
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct ParserState {
    pub target: String,
    pub index: usize,
    pub result: Option<String>, // the container of eventual results from the parsing, with Some(result) or None
    pub error: bool,            // whether we've encountered an error; index -> 0, Some(err_msg)
    pub err_msg: Option<String> // Eventual error message
}

impl<F> Parser<F> 
    where F: Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    pub fn new(f: F) -> Self {
        // creating a new Parser just means deciding on which closure it applies
        Parser {
            transformer: f,
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&self, corpus: String) -> ParserState {
        let state = ParserState {
            target: corpus,
            index: 0,
            result: None,
            error: false,
            err_msg: None
        };
        return (self.transformer)(state);
    }
}

pub fn str_parser(needle: String) -> impl Fn(ParserState) -> ParserState {
    move |mut state: ParserState| {
        let target_string = state.target;
        let index = state.index;
        if target_string[index..needle.len()] == needle {
            state = ParserState {
                target: target_string,
                index: index + needle.len(),
                result: Some(needle.clone()),
                error: false,
                err_msg: None
            }
        } else {
            state = ParserState {
                target: String::from(""),
                index: 0,
                result: None,
                error: true,
                err_msg: Some(String::from("Error"))
            }
        }
        state
    }
}
```